# Printing pdf with just the answer, rather than the whole page

Tags: discussion, support, printing

Some answer are so interesting that I would like to print them, to read them again later on.

I would also like to take advantage of the latex format, instead of printing the whole page, and print a pdf with just the answer.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128703/can-i-print-a-single-answer

Comment: There is also a previous question on our site, [How to print a Cross Validated question or answer?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/2180/1036). Not sure of an easy way to just print the answers though.

Comment: @AndyW I think I'll go with your solution, but it would be nice to have an option, like the 'edit', 'share', and so on, that are directly under the question or answer.

Comment: +1 that's a really nice idea. It would make our site even more valuable to those who seek knowledge of statistics.

Answer (score 5):

I'll summarize the options. Two solutions are offered in [Can I print a single answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128703/259867):

1. Userscript [Print this Post](https://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post) by Manishearth which suppresses everything on the page except the selected posts.
2. [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), which prints all posts on the page (optionally, suppressing comments).

One more solution (mine) is [Save Q&A as LaTeX](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/savetex.html), which converts both the question and its answers to LaTeX. One can delete the question and unwanted answers before printing, although the question is useful for context.

For illustration, I used [Dummy variables to control for clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137544/dummy-variables-to-control-clustered-sample) and copy-pasted LaTeX output into [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/), obtaining [this PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/dummy-variables-control.pdf).

Comment: Trying to use your solution but it does not work... after hitting the button to save a page as pdf, I get nothing...